# View Pager change dynamic height on scroll

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, android-cardview, android-scrollview

I have a ViewPager and scrolling list view items but I want height of the ViewPager be dynamic based after list view scrolling. So When I scroll list view items towards view pager, three view pager on one screen should changing its height.

My ViewPager and list view looks like this.

[image]

and I want to achieve this view after scrolling my list view towards viewpager so first and third both corner view pager with middle one should change its view like this.

[image]

I tried Sticky Header library to achieve this but I didn't get success.
Please help me achieve this or is there any library to do this ?

Comment: do you want the 3 boxes to change in size while the user scrolls?

Comment: @mremremre1 Yes, I want the 3 boxes to change in size dynamically while the user scrolls. but I don't know how to achieve this.